# Why is this constructor (using "new Function") breaking?

Tags: javascript, templates, constructor, frameworks

I'm brand new to JS and am trying to build a template function (assignment in a MOOC) that basically returns a function that returns the rendered template based on an input string and delimiter.

Anyway, this is the code that I have so far and I have no idea why it is breaking.. I've really tried everything that I can think of!

```
var template = function(stringToParse, options) {

    // find out if custom delimiters are being used
    if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
        var openDelim = options.open;
        var closeDelim = options.close;
    } else {
        var openDelim = '*(';
        var closeDelim = ')*';
    }

    // get the length of the closing delim for parsing later
    var delimCharLen = closeDelim.length;

    // helper function
    function parseOutFiller(_array) {

        // get an array of the indices of each closing delim in the string
        var closingDelims = [];
        for (i=0; i < _array.length; i++) {
            closingDelims.push(_array[i].indexOf(closeDelim));
        }

        // remove the filler text leading up to the closing dim in each substring
        for (i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
            if (closingDelims[i] > 0) {
                _array[i] = _array[i].slice(closingDelims[i] + delimCharLen)
            }
        }

        return _array
    }

    // split array, get the closing indices, and parse out the filler text
    var splitArray = stringToParse.split(openDelim);
    var parsedString = parseOutFiller(splitArray);

    return new Function("var locParsedString = [" + parsedString + "];\
                         var inputCopy = [];\
                         for (i=0; i < arguments.length-1; i++) {\
                             inputCopy.push(arguments[i])\
                         }\
                         var templateString = '';\
                         for (i=0; i < inputCopy.length; i++) {\
                             templateString += locParsedString[i];\
                             templateString += inputCopy[i];\
                         }\
                         templateString += locParsedString[locParsedString.length-1];\
                         nRepeat = arguments[arguments.length-1];\
                         for (i=0; i < nRepeat; i++) {\
                             console.log(templateString);\
                         }"
                       )
}
```

Then when I run it...

```
var string = "Is <<! thing !>> healthy to <<! action !>>?";
var logResult = template(string, {open: '<<!', close: '!>>'});

logResult('this', 'eat', 3)

/*

Which should print:

"Is this healthy to eat?"
"Is this healthy to eat?"
"Is this healthy to eat?"

*/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's really no reason to build the function from a string like that.

Comment: I mean I also thought it was pretty unreasonable, but that's how they are teaching it in the class

Comment: you should complain. Generally such an approach would be uniformly frowned upon by actual professional programmers.

Comment: @Pointy good to know!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using new Function(), just use return function () { }. 
That way, there is no need to create locParserString inside the function. You can use parsedString directly:

```
var template = function(stringToParse, options) {

    // find out if custom delimiters are being used
    if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
        var openDelim = options.open;
        var closeDelim = options.close;
    } else {
        var openDelim = '*(';
        var closeDelim = ')*';
    }

    // get the length of the closing delim for parsing later
    var delimCharLen = closeDelim.length;

    // helper function
    function parseOutFiller(_array) {

        // get an array of the indices of each closing delim in the string
        var closingDelims = [];
        for (i=0; i < _array.length; i++) {
            closingDelims.push(_array[i].indexOf(closeDelim));
        }

        // remove the filler text leading up to the closing dim in each substring
        for (i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
            if (closingDelims[i] > 0) {
                _array[i] = _array[i].slice(closingDelims[i] + delimCharLen)
            }
        }

        return _array
    }

    // split array, get the closing indices, and parse out the filler text
    var splitArray = stringToParse.split(openDelim);
    var parsedString = parseOutFiller(splitArray);

    return function () {
        var inputCopy = [];
        for (i=0; i < arguments.length-1; i++) {
            inputCopy.push(arguments[i])
        }
        var templateString = '';
        for (i=0; i < inputCopy.length; i++) {
            templateString += parsedString[i];
            templateString += inputCopy[i];
        }
        templateString += parsedString[parsedString.length-1];
        nRepeat = arguments[arguments.length-1];
        for (i=0; i < nRepeat; i++) {
            console.log(templateString);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Ah that worked -- thank you! For my own understanding, is there any benefits in using the `new Function` constructor? Or are the certain situations when using is is better? The class had us specifically using that (`new Function`) but this is just so much easier (and cleaner!)

Comment: @Zach building code from a string of source code is only necessary in very rare situations.